Speakers not working on 24.04 LTS install
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on a Dell XPS One 2710.
The speakers are not functioning. Only headphones work. Weirdly, the speakers were running when the headphones were plugged in, but when removed, they stopped. Re-inserting the headphone jack didn't bring back the speakers. I tried the usual sound setting troubleshooting, but no luck.
I have looked up the sound card:
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family
High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04).

What do we think? Driver update/install?

"I tried the usual sound setting troubleshooting, but no luck." What did you try, info needed.
